# SQL: Finding the "new users" to "returning users" ratio

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table as below:

| answer_id | user_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 2020-01 |
| 2 | 33 | 2020-02 |
| 3 | 78 | 2020-03 |
| 4 | 33 | 3030-04 |

what I need to do is to find the ratio of the new to returning users. By new, I mean the user_ids that were appeared only once, such as 22 and 78. And by returning users, I mean the user_ids that appeared more than once, such as 33.For example, the output should be something like this ----> 2:1
I need to do it with SQL and I though maybe I should create two temporary tables like the following:

```
with table_a as(
select user_id , count(answer_id) 
from 1
group by 1
having count(answer_id)>1
)                     
table_b as (
select user_id , count(answer_id) 
from b
group by 1
having count(answer_id)<2
)
```

the first table returns the user_ids that were repeated more than once, and the second table returns the number of ids that were unique. However, I am just lost what to do next. first time I tried it, I wanted to join them somehow, but I cannot join them as there aren't any matching field. Can any one help me on how I can find the ratio?

Comment: Please define "new" and "repeating" user.  Also show the results that you want so the explanation is clear.

Comment: I edited the question and defined them. The output should be something like 2:1

Answer (score 2):

You just want to find out how many have a frequency of one and how many have a frequency higher than one.  You can manipulate the output however you'd like later.

```
SELECT sum(vol=1) as newUsers, 
    sum(vol>1) as returning,
    count(*) as total
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, count(*) as vol
    FROM table GROUP BY user_id
) z
```

Comment: If that solved your problem remember to accept the answer. :)